# Simulink Rapid Accelerator rebuild for variable input data

Tags: matlab, simulink

I just discovered a bad bug because I trusted Simulink too much to care about all dependencies when using Rapid Accelerator.

Basically I have hundreds of iterations running over the same model but with different input data (coming from MATLAB workspace over "From Workspace").

Simulink seems to ignore dependencies on input data and won't rebuild the target accordingly for fresh input data.

Now I can force a rebuild for every iteration but this is not the point of an optimized model ...

How can I tell Simulink to just compile a single file containg the input + linker (which is build every iteration) rather than building the whole model?

Even if this does not work: How do I force a rebuild in the first place?

Neither

```
 Simulink.BlockDiagram.buildRapidAcceleratorTarget('my_model');
```

more setting "Rebuild all (including libraries)" in the Simulation Target settings seems to **force** a rebuild ....

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it's a well documented fact.

When a model containing a "From Workspace" block is compiled into a Rapid Accelerator target, the standalone executable will contain all relevant variables in the workspace, with sizes and values equal to the ones they have *at compilation time*.

This is a good enough reason to avoid blocks like "From Workspace" by default, except in quick-n-dirty normal mode simulations.

It is kind of obvious if you think about it -- consider what would happen if your model uses a variable in the workspace

```
myVar = [1 2 3];
```

during its first run, but at the next run you set

```
myVar = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
```

This kind of flexibility is trivial in the MATLAB/Simulink environment, but implementing it in a language like C or C++ is much harder. Although generating this flexibility into the Rapid Acceleration target *is* possible, I wouldn't recommend it.

A much better approach is to use inports to your model, or even better, model parameters. These are elaborated for example, [in this blog post](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/34949-rapid-accelerator-simulation), and various other places.

Comment: Actually, are you **really sure** about this? Because in the meantime I tried out certain things and found out that if I change workspace data for the "From Workspace" block I still get the _correct_ result! I definitely use Rapid Accelerator. Your argument wrt "From Workspace" is not valid: In this case any reasonably good compile chain would automatically build all dependent files (usually a smaller subset) which is exactly the behavior of any "make" and the behavior I would naturally expect from Simulink. But based on my tests this seems true?

Comment: One more remark: Maybe this behavior has changed (I use R2015a)?

Comment: Wait, what? So you change the workspace data, and without rebuilding, you get different output? Then... What's your problem? All I know is that it doesn't work on R2010a (what I'm still using, unfortunately), for the reason I indicated. That's the whole point of model parameters and tunability... Well, maybe they changed it, I sure hope so.

Comment: Yes. I have something like `for simin=1:100;sim test;end`. All variability for me comes from "From Workspace". Not sure what exactly happens in the background but no message like `### Building the rapid accelerator target for model` except for the first iteration. If it would not take this into account, all runs should give the same result, right? But they don't ... May I prepare a simple example to cross check?

Comment: What went wrong initially then? What happened that caused you to post this question and what did you change?

Comment: I created an example with all outputs/screenshots in https://www.dropbox.com/s/9psjlhs6k564nzg/test_rapid.zip?dl=0 . The mdl file is exported for R2010a, maybe you can check it there? The original question was because I got results that I could not explain (_maybe_ unrelated) and I wanted to make sure that I can exclude that some data messes up due to this build because I saw the actual data in the source files and got uncomfortable.